# Django 1.3 and South migrations

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures, django-south

I have an existing project which extensively uses South migrations to load data into its tables.

Since upgrading to Django 1.3 our unit tests no longer run because they cannot find the data they rely on.

1. Is this behaviour is due to [one of the backwards incompatible changes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#use-of-custom-sql-to-load-initial-data-in-tests) in 1.3
2. Is there an easy way for me to convert all these migrations into fixtures?

Comment: You could perhaps try deleting the `migrations` folder in each app directory and run `./manage.py schemamigration app --initial`? Make a backup of everything first, because this may or may not work.

Comment: This would work for my unit tests, but would break my production systems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, this behavior is due to this change.

   There seems to be a workaround in South trunk (see https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/changeset/21a635231327 ) so you can try South development version (it is quite stable in my experience).
2. You may try to change the DB name in settings (in order to get clean environment), run `./manage.py syncdb` and `./manage.py migrate` and then do `./manage.py dumpdata`

Comment: As at 2012-01-19, there still hasn't been a south release with that fix, but you can pip install south from trunk with:

`pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south`

*But* - it doesn't fix the problem as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue today. Eventually I ended up refactoring my migrations so that they use helper functions to actually insert the data, and then calling the same functions from the setUp() of my tests.

Some hints;

- Make your helper functions take the model class as an argument, so you can call them with orm['yourapp.YourModel'] from the migration and with models.YourModel from the test. That also shows the main limitation: South works for models whose schema has changed since then, the test code can't do that. I was lucky in that this particular model hasn't changed.
- If you want to keep the helper methods inside the migrations, you'll find that you can't directly import yourapp.migrations.0001_some_migration because identifiers can't start with numbers. Use something like `migration_0001 = importlib.import_module('yourapp.migrations.0001_some_migration')` instead of an import statement.